# Gearmand Does Not Start - Socket Address Family Not Supported

Tags: ubuntu, docker, gearman

I am trying to run the Gearman Job Server on a `Docker` container running on an Ubuntu host machine. However, upon startup, I get an error: `[ main ] socket()(Address family not supported by protocol) -> libgearman-server/gearmand.cc:470`.

I tried disabling `IPv6` on the host machine but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved. It had nothing to do with Gearman and Docker but with the particular Ubuntu installation. After reformatting, everything worked as it should

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well with a alpine tomcat docker image. It seems that docker does not have all the kinks worked out when it comes to IPv6 being disabled on the host.

In my case, and what I suspect was the underlying issue that a reformat resolved for you is that IPv6 WAS disabled on the host, but the guest container was trying to use it, and docker can't handle that. Reformatting would have re-enabled IPv6 in the kernel(it can still be disabled on a case by case basis for interfaces), thus allowing docker to use it in the guest.

[Nginx not starting when IPv6 is not enabled in host machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48398893/nginx-not-starting-when-ipv6-is-not-enabled-in-host-machine)